# how to redirect to different URL?

Tags: linux, iptables, filtering

I want to redirect the request to my machine to another URL[not IP address]. Is there any way to achieve this using iptables?.. or what is the way to achieve this?..

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't follow, what are you trying to accomplish? What iptables rule did you create (maybe post the command)?

Comment: What are you trying to do, why in god's name would you redirect to another port if you don't have anything running on there?

Comment: "2.Is there any way to redirect to particular URL rather redirect to IP address or Port?." 

Sounds like he wants an HTTP redirect. @user1216216 Please explain to us what you're trying to accomplish, not how you are trying to accomplish it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Iptables is used for ipv4 packet filtering. What you want is redirecting an url, which is part of http(rotocol). For forwarding an URL you can use a (simple) webserver, and configure it to forward request to another url.

Depending on your forward requirements this can be a simple html file with

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.example.com/" />
```

Or a complicated ruleset using Apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: mod_rewrite complicated?   Nah.  Well documented, used extensively and once mastered very powerful.  Just need to get your head around Regex.

Comment: Agreed, I meant his requirements for forwarding may be complicated :)